# Get event on UIslider track

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uislider

How to get an event on UISlider track? I am able to get the events on UISlider's button but not on track. How should I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: Will you please let us know what your mean by Slider track ? You want the event for slider or something else ?

Comment: The track on which the slider moves. Slider has two parts Thumb and track. I am looking for an event while tapping on the track not the thumb.

Comment: I don't think you can get these events directly unless you subclass the UISlider class or creating your own controller similar to UISlider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass the `UISlider` and override its `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method. Get the point value from the touch event and calculate it's percentage by the point's .x value relative to the width of the slider.

Answer (score 4):

For doing this you need to subclass the `UISlider` and implement the touches event like: touchesBegan, touchesEnd,touchesCancelled,touchesMoved etc.

```
@interface yourSlider:UISlider
@end

@implementation yourSlider
  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    }

  - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    }

  - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    }

  - (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    }
@end
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks everyone for their responses.. I tried the subclassing but found it somewhat longer, though useful, method. What I did instead was I made the thumb image larger with equal transparent areas(equal to the length of unused track) on both sides. This expanded the touch area and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Answers are correct but there is a workaround here , you can simply add a clear button equal to slider coordinations on your slider and detect the touch point on it then convert the X position to a slider value.

```
    - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
     {
       UIView *button = (UIView *)sender;
       UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];
       CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:button];
       NSLog(@"Location in button: %f, %f", location.x, location.y); \\ use this x to determine slider's value

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround :

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self             action:@selector(sliderTapped:)];
gr.delegate=self;
[Slider addGestureRecognizer:gr];

-(void)sliderTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)g{
UISlider* s = (UISlider*)g.view;
if (s.highlighted)
    return; 
CGPoint pt = [g locationInView: s];
CGFloat value = s.minimumValue + pt.x / s.bounds.size.width * (s.maximumValue - s.minimumValue);
[s setValue:value animated:YES];
}
```